# What exactly "take" means "take some aspirin"? Buying or having?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

In Advices like "take some vitamin C", "take some aspirin" etc. Take mean buying or eating?

Comment: Hello Rihi, dictionaries answer this question.  See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/take  and scroll down.  You will see "take verb [T] (MEDICINE) *to swallow or use medicine*"

Comment: advice, not advices. [Question: What exactly **does** "take some aspirin" **mean**?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Taking medicine", "taking a pill", "taking an aspirin", etc. all mean to **consume** the medicine, whatever it may be.

Comment: We eat food. We don't normally use 'eat' in relation to medicine, we normally use words like 'swallow', 'inhale', 'inject', etc. I have asthma and I take a medication called Fostair (beclometasone dipropionate and formoterol) twice a day using an [inhaler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inhaler).

Comment: Although the British National Formulary lists products like 'Fortipudding', a diet supplement used in cases of malnutrition, and I would think you eat that.